# How do I make row position fixed without destroying col-.. attributes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's a fiddle that shows what I'm trying to do.

I want to make sure that the row is fixed position, however upon either

1. Adding a div inside the row element and making it position: fixed destroys col sizings
2. Adding a div outside the row element does the same as the above.

How do I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22904/

```
 <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4 id="currentlyTagging">Currently tagging:</h4>
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <select id="tagSelection" ng-model="myModel" data-style="btn-primary" required class="list-selector form-control"
            ng-options="tag.name for tag in v.tagListFromDatabase" ng-change="v.select(myModel.name)">
              <option value='' disabled>Select a label</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4" >
              <span title="Save changes"class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" id="done-button" ng-click="v.done()"></span>
              <span title="Cancel and return to images" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" id="cancel-button" ui-sref='imageListState'></span>
              <span title="Delete Image" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" id="delete-button" ng-click="v.openDeleteModal()"></span>
            </div>


    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" id="imageControlBar">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" id="next-button" ng-click="v.next()"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: where did you intend for the row to be positioned? fixed at the top? By setting `position: fixed;` you are removing it from the flow of the document, at which point sizing and positioning will be up to you (and any relevant remaining Bootstrap code).

Comment: I wanted it to be positioned right after the dummy text(which is also fixed in my actual code) in fiddle. And fixed there.

Comment: `position: fixed;` means positioned based upon the window - you can position that box 50% from the top, for example, but it would not be fixed if it was positioned based on the text above it.

Comment: So would it not be possible to fix the row position and keep the bootstrap attributes? Do I have to override bootstrap css to make the columns sizing and positioning like I want?

Answer (score 0):

I use SASS but I'm sure you can translate it.

The HTML

```
    <header>
        <div id="header-content"></div>
    </header>
```

The SASS / CSS

```
header{
    @extend .row;
    position:absolute;
}

#header-content{
    @include make-sm-column(3);
    position:fixed;
}
```

I now have a fixed column that is still part of the grid and still sized correctly.

**edit:** Thanks for the downvote? It's literally a matter of replacing the @extend and @include in the SCSS with classes in the HTML.